# Converting column to decimal in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following lines of code

```
Select 0 as Stipend
```

and then to actually add a value to stipend I do this

```
COALESCE(SUM(sdhi.stipend), 0, CONVERT(decimal(16, 4), 0)) Stipend
```

But it returns as 0 and not as a decimal for the columns, how can I convert this to decimal?

Comment: Result of this query `Select COALESCE(SUM(0),0, CONVERT(decimal(16,4), 0 )) as Stipend ` is `0.0000` . i cant find any problem

Comment: @Amirhossein it returns the value as 0 for me and not 0.000

Comment: what is column sdhi.stipend data type?

Comment: Try this -  `COALESCE(SUM(sdhi.stipend), CONVERT(decimal(16, 4), 0))`

Comment: Why would you provide 2 versions of zero to `Coalesce()`? It will return as soon as it gets a non-`null` value, which obviously `0` will always be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server `COALESCE()` function returns the first non-null value in a list:

Your column `sdhi.stipend` data is `NULL` then your second argument is `0` then result is second argument.

If column `sdhi.stipend` data type is decimal or money you need this:

```
 Select COALESCE(SUM(sdhi.stipend), CONVERT(decimal(16,4), 0 )) as Stipend
```

Answer (score 2):

0.000 is the same as 0. The DECIMAL data type does not define the formatting of the value, just how it is stored. This means, the representation of said value depends on the client software, like SSMS or a web app.

Formatting the value should be done by the client software (SSMS does it for you with it's current default settings, others might not)

This line is overcomplicated:

```
COALESCE(SUM(sdhi.stipend), 0, CONVERT(decimal(16, 4), 0)) Stipend
```

Besides that, the data type of literal value 0 is `decimal(1,0)`, therefore the result will be `decimal(1,0)` when `SUM(sdhi.stipend)` is NULL (which can only happen if you have only NULL values in the group you are summing or the table is empty).

This is enough if you want to force `DECIMAL(16,4)` as the data type.

```
COALESCE(SUM(sdhi.stipend), CONVERT(decimal(16, 4), 0)) Stipend
```

Be aware, that the result of SUM(sdhi.stipend) might have different precision and scale (depending on the data you have stored in the column). Therefore you might want to consider the following:

```
CONVERT(decimal(16, 4), COALESCE(SUM(sdhi.stipend), 0)) AS Stipend
```

The problem with this is that when the result of `SUM(sdhi.stipend)` exceeds the limits of `decimal(16, 4)` you'll get overflow errors.

Choose wisely and read a bit about decimal arithmetic in SQL Server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15